# Maven artifacts could not be resolved

Tags: maven-2, maven, maven-3, pom.xml

I added the spring and jboss repositories to my pom.xml like below:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <name>MyProject</name>
    <url>http://www.myproject.com</url>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.myproject</groupId>
    <artifactId>myproject</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>   
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.3-b02</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.3_01</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0-alpha-1</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
            <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- SPRING DEPENDENCIES -->
        <dependency>  
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>  
            <artifactId>spring</artifactId>  
            <version>3.0.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- HIBERNATE DEPENDENCIES -->
        <dependency>  
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>  
            <artifactId>hibernate</artifactId>  
            <version>3.5.4-Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- PRIMEFACES -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.M4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces.themes</groupId>
            <artifactId>aristo</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- OTHER DEPENDENCIES -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <version>1.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.18</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.authorize</groupId>
            <artifactId>java-anet-sdk</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ocpsoft</groupId>
            <artifactId>prettyfaces-jsf2</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>6.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <netbeans.hint.j2eeVersion>1.6</netbeans.hint.j2eeVersion>
        <netbeans.hint.deploy.server>gfv3ee6</netbeans.hint.deploy.server>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>jsf20</id>
            <name>Repository for library Library[jsf20]</name>
            <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2/</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>
        <repository>  
            <id>prime-repo</id>  
            <name>PrimeFaces Maven Repository</name>  
            <url>http://repository.primefaces.org</url>  
            <layout>default</layout> 
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>jboss-public-repository-group</id>
            <name>JBoss Public Maven Repository Group</name>
            <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases/</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-release</id>
            <name>Spring Release Repository</name>
            <url>http://maven.springframework.org/release</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                    <compilerArguments>
                        <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                    </compilerArguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                            <silent>true</silent>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                    <version>6.0</version>
                                    <type>jar</type>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
    </build>
    <!--pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>caucho</id>
            <name>Caucho</name>
            <url>http://caucho.com/m2</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories-->
</project>
```

But when I build, I get an error:

```
The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.springframework:spring:jar:3.0.6.RELEASE, org.hibernate:hibernate:jar:3.5.4-Final: Could not find artifact org.springframework:spring:jar:3.0.6.RELEASE in jsf20 (http://download.java.net/maven/2/) -> [Help 1]
```

It's like maven only looks at the first repository and not the ones defined for spring and hibernate.

**Update:** Ran with -X and -e options at command line but not very useful from what I can tell: http://pastebin.com/c7nPzBc2

Comment: Odd because spring is available in maven central.  There should be no need for a special repo for that.  Also, I would recommend only including the spring artifacts you are actually using.  Chances are you dont use _everything_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That error just says it cant be found at the java.net repo, it should continue on and check the others until it finds one that does have it.  You should be able to safely ignore that.

Also, the url you have listed for spring appears to be dead, it gives me error 500 when i try to go there directly.  Either way, its unnecessary as the spring artifacts can be found in maven central (at least through 3.0.6 which you are listing as your dependency).

---

After a little more investigation, i find that spring has not published a `spring` artifact since [2.5.6](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3a%22org.springframework%22%20AND%20a%3a%22spring%22).  You will need to specify each artifact individually.  For example:

```
<dependency>  
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>  
  <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>  
  <version>3.0.6.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>  
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>  
  <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>  
  <version>3.0.6.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>  
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>  
  <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>  
  <version>3.0.6.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
...
```

Comment: I get that error when I try to build in Netbeans and it says "Build Failure" because of it.

Comment: Try building the same project from the command line.  And use the -X option for more details.  Could be that it tries the next repo, gets the error 500 and quits.  Not sure though...