# Drools: cannot start container on remote kie-server, for "Could not find artifact ..."

Tags: drools, kie-workbench

On a server with drools workbench and KIE server both installed, I authored a project, and got it built and deployed. Also, **I can start a container for it locally**.

But I **could not create a container for it on a remote server**, and got the following error on remote server:

```
Unable to resolve artifact: testdrools:firstApplication:pom:1.3
org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: Could not find artifact testdrools:firstApplication:pom:1.3 in central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/)
```

With the limited knowledge on MAVEN I learnt from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27110014/could-not-find-artifact-in-maven-central-repo-when-search-returns-a-match), it seems what the KIE server tries to resolve, "**testdrools:firstApplication:pom:1.3**", does exist, since part of the pom.xml extracted from *.jar file is as follows:

```
  <groupId>testdrools</groupId>
  <artifactId>firstApplication</artifactId>
  <version>1.3</version>
  <name>firstApplication</name>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.kie</groupId>
        <artifactId>kie-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>6.2.0.Final</version>
        <extensions>true</extensions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Could somebody give me any hint on **why I can't create a remote container for this case**?

---

We found **a workaround** for this problem. While trying to re-produce this problem, we got the error again:

```
Could not find artifact droolstest:droolsTestProj2:pom:1.1 in local (file:/root/.m2/repository/)
```

So we downloaded the "droolsTestProj2-1.1.jar" file from artifact repository of workbench, and copy it to "/root/.m2/repository/droolstest/droolsTestProj2/1.1". Container started up after refreshing.

It seems workbench failed to send the *.jar file to KIE server. Share your ideas on this, please.

Answer (score 2):

Can you try to set a custom `settings.xml` which would contain reference to local repository? This repository can be shared between workbench and Kie server.

To set a custom `settings.xml` you need to define the system property `"kie.maven.settings.custom"` in containers where you run applications.

This property should reference to location of your `settings.xml` file. In that file you should define tag `<localRepository>`, which will reference the directory where you will place the local repository shared between workbench and Kie server.

For more info, see the [Drools Documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/latest/drools-docs/html_single/).

Comment: With all the PAAS solutions out there, you no longer control the files on the server. How would you remotely deploy the jar file and a settings.xml file, and then point to that settings.xml?

Comment: @terminatur one approach is to have the KIE execution servers look up an external Maven repository, for example the business central workbench hosted repo at http://server:port/business-cetran/maven2.  See, the ```KIE_MAVEN_REPO``` environment variable in the [Dockerfile](https://hub.docker.com/r/jboss/kie-server-showcase/dockerfile).  See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40222294/cant-deploy-artifact-to-kie-server-via-drools-workbench-because-of-conversatio) question.