# Failure to deploy from workbench to kie-server

Tags: drools, workbench, kie

I attempted to create a new project in kie-workbench (6.2.0.Final) and deploy it to the remote kie-server (6.2.0.Final). I create the container via the workbench then hit the "start" button for the container. When I hit start, a red error icon appears next to the server and the container.

When I go to the URL specified in the Container Info side panel, (http://192.168.1.11:8080/kie-server-6.2.0.Final-webc/services/rest/server/containers/test
) I get the following response XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<response type="SUCCESS" msg="Info for container test">
  <kie-container container-id="test" status="FAILED">
    <scanner status="DISPOSED"/>
  </kie-container>
</response>
```

Is there a log file I can go to get more information? I am running kie-server and kie-workbench on Tomcat 7.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe '**TOMCAT_HOME\logs\catalina.log**' is what you're looking for? If you also want to see the log in terminal, you can modify 'TOMCAT_HOME\logs\startup.sh'. That is, changing

```
exec "$PRGDIR"/"$EXECUTABLE" start "$@"
```

into

```
exec "$PRGDIR"/"$EXECUTABLE" run "$@"
```

Though I can make some containers start up correctly, I'm still facing some problems, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31613634/drools-cannot-start-container-on-remote-kie-server-for-could-not-find-artifac).

**For your reference**, I can see the following response on the link you provide when container started up correctly:

```
<response type="SUCCESS" msg="List of created containers">
    <kie-containers>
        <kie-container container-id="droolsTest" status="STARTED">
            <release-id>
                <artifact-id>droolsTestProj</artifact-id>
                <group-id>demo</group-id>
                <version>2.0</version>
            </release-id>
            <resolved-release-id>
                <artifact-id>droolsTestProj</artifact-id>
                <group-id>demo</group-id>
                <version>2.0</version>
            </resolved-release-id>
            <scanner status="DISPOSED"/>
        </kie-container>
    </kie-containers>
</response>
```