# Can't deploy artifact to KIE-server via Drools workbench because of "ConversationId not valid - missing releaseId"

Tags: java, docker, drools, docker-compose, kie-server

I'm using the, kie-server-showcase and drools-workbench-showcase, via docker-run, I can see the kie-server in the drools UI and deploy a build to it.

[image]

However, when I use docker-compose, I get a runtime exception when trying to deploy the demo morgauge project, see the logs here: http://pastebin.com/qKQ8hgak, but I've included the interesting parts:

```
kie-server               | 15:24:41,268 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015874: WildFly 8.2.0.Final "Tweek" started in 15690ms - Started 406 of 458 services (106 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)
kie-server               | 15:24:50,369 WARN  [org.kie.server.services.impl.controller.DefaultRestControllerImpl] (KieServer-ControllerConnect) Exception encountered while syncing with controller at http://kie_wb:8080/drools-wb/rest/controller/server/kie-server-3aec89f430c2 error Error while sending PUT request to http://kie_wb:8080/drools-wb/rest/controller/server/kie-server-3aec89f430c2 response code 405
kie-server               | 15:25:00,376 WARN  [org.kie.server.services.impl.controller.DefaultRestControllerImpl] (KieServer-ControllerConnect) Exception encountered while syncing with controller at http://kie_wb:8080/drools-wb/rest/controller/server/kie-server-3aec89f430c2 error Error while sending PUT request to http://kie_wb:8080/drools-wb/rest/controller/server/kie-server-3aec89f430c2 response code 405
kie-server               | 15:25:10,383 WARN  [org.kie.server.services.impl.controller.DefaultRestControllerImpl] (KieServer-ControllerConnect) Exception encountered while syncing with controller at http://kie_wb:8080/drools-wb/rest/controller/server/kie-server-3aec89f430c2 error Error while sending PUT request to http://kie_wb:8080/drools-wb/rest/controller/server/kie-server-3aec89f430c2 response code 405
kie-server               | 15:25:23,534 INFO  [org.kie.server.services.impl.controller.ControllerConnectRunnable] (KieServer-ControllerConnect) Connected to controller, quiting connector thread
kie-server               | 15:25:23,536 INFO  [org.kie.server.services.impl.ContainerManager] (EJB default - 5) About to install containers '[]' on kie server 'KieServer{id='kie-server-3aec89f430c2'name='kie-server-3aec89f430c2'version='6.4.0.Final'location='http://172.18.0.3:8080/kie-server/services/rest/server'}'
kie-server               | 15:26:17,419 WARN  [org.kie.scanner.embedder.MavenSettings] (default task-3) Environment variable M2_HOME is not set
kie-server               | 15:26:17,588 INFO  [org.kie.scanner.Aether] (default task-3) The local repository directory /opt/jboss/.m2/repository doesn't exist. Creating it.
kie-server               | 15:26:18,932 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-5) UT005023: Exception handling request to /kie-server/services/rest/server/containers/demo: org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: ConversationId not valid - missing releaseId

...

kie-server               | 15:26:19,231 WARN  [org.kie.scanner.MavenRepository] (default task-3) Unable to resolve artifact: mortgages:mortgages:0.0.1
kie-server               | 15:26:20,269 WARN  [org.kie.scanner.MavenRepository] (default task-3) Unable to resolve artifact: mortgages:mortgages:pom:0.0.1
kie-server               | 15:26:20,269 ERROR [org.kie.server.services.impl.KieServerImpl] (default task-3) Error creating container 'demo' for module 'mortgages:mortgages:0.0.1': java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot find KieModule: mortgages:mortgages:0.0.1
kie-server               |  at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieServicesImpl.newKieContainer(KieServicesImpl.java:117) [drools-compiler-6.4.0.Final.jar:6.4.0.Final]
```

[image]

Here's the docker-compose.yml files I use:

```
version: '2'

services:

  drools-wb:
    container_name: drools-wb
    image: jboss/drools-workbench-showcase:latest
    ports:
      - 8001:8001
      - 18080:8080
    networks:
      - mckinsey-net

  kie-server:
    container_name: kie-server
    image: jboss/kie-server-showcase:latest
    links:
      - drools-wb:kie_wb
    depends_on:
      - drools-wb
    environment:
      - HOME=/opt/jboss
      - JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java
      - JAVA_OPTS=-XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Xms256m -Xmx512m
      - JBOSS_BIND_ADDRESS=0.0.0.0
      - JBOSS_HOME=/opt/jboss/wildfly
      - KIE_CLASSIFIER=ee7
      - KIE_CONTEXT_PATH=kie-server
      - KIE_MAVEN_REPO=http://localhost:8080/kie-wb/maven2
      - KIE_MAVEN_REPO_PASSWORD=admin
      - KIE_MAVEN_REPO_USER=admin
      - KIE_REPOSITORY=https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public-jboss
      - KIE_SERVER_CONTROLLER_PWD=admin
      - KIE_SERVER_CONTROLLER_USER=admin
      - KIE_SERVER_LOCATION=http://localhost:8080/kie-server/services/rest/server
      - KIE_SERVER_PWD=kieserver1!
      - KIE_SERVER_USER=kieserver
      - KIE_VERSION=6.4.0.Final
      - KIE_WB_ENV_JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java
      - KIE_WB_ENV_JAVA_OPTS=-XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Xms256m -Xmx512m
      - KIE_WB_ENV_JBOSS_BIND_ADDRESS=0.0.0.0
      - KIE_WB_ENV_JBOSS_HOME=/opt/jboss/wildfly
      - KIE_WB_ENV_KIE_CLASSIFIER=wildfly8
      - KIE_WB_ENV_KIE_CONTEXT_PATH=drools-wb
      - KIE_WB_ENV_KIE_DEMO=true
      - KIE_WB_ENV_KIE_REPOSITORY=https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public-jboss
      - KIE_WB_ENV_KIE_SERVER_PROFILE=standalone-full-drools
      - KIE_WB_ENV_KIE_VERSION=6.4.0.Final
      - KIE_WB_ENV_WILDFLY_VERSION=8.2.0.Final
      - KIE_WB_NAME=/kie-server/kie_wb
      - KIE_WB_PORT=tcp://kie_wb:8001
      - KIE_WB_PORT_8001_TCP=tcp://kie_wb:8001
      - KIE_WB_PORT_8001_TCP_ADDR=kie_wb
      - KIE_WB_PORT_8001_TCP_PORT=8001
      - KIE_WB_PORT_8001_TCP_PROTO=tcp
      - KIE_WB_PORT_8080_TCP=tcp://kie_wb:8080
      - KIE_WB_PORT_8080_TCP_ADDR=kie_wb
      - KIE_WB_PORT_8080_TCP_PORT=8080
      - KIE_WB_PORT_8080_TCP_PROTO=tcp
      - KIE_WB_PORT_9990_TCP=tcp://kie_wb:9990
      - KIE_WB_PORT_9990_TCP_ADDR=kie_wb
      - KIE_WB_PORT_9990_TCP_PORT=9990
      - KIE_WB_PORT_9990_TCP_PROTO=tcp
      - PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
      - WILDFLY_VERSION=8.2.0.Final
```

I'm not sure why it can't resolve that artifact. Any ideas?

Comment: Per @Roger's comment, looks like a Maven repo issue. The environment ```KIE_MAVEN_REPO=http://localhost:8080/kie-wb/maven2``` should be changed to ```KIE_MAVEN_REPO=http://drools-wb:8080/business-central/maven2```.  This will tell the KIE execution server to look up the workbench's Maven repo instead of looking at the KIE execution server's own internal Maven repo (which won't contain the artifacts).

Answer (score 1):

You have to check basically two connections between the workbench and the kie-server, if they're running on different nodes - the HTTP ones provided by the kie-server REST endpoints and the system maven configuration on the kie-server as well, so it have to use the workbench as source repository for artifacts.

Looking at the stracktrace, I see some 405 errors when running the container and are probably related, endpoints are visible but not allowed... Did you try making some requests to the kie-server endpoints via some other client or command line? Have the user the right role? See example instructions [here](https://github.com/jboss-dockerfiles/drools/tree/master/kie-server/showcase)

Comment: I'll look into that now, however as a follow up, why do the containers behave differently when run via `docker run` and `docker-compose`?

Comment: I've created a newer, more concise question, relating directly to the Maven connection. Please see - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40388208/cannot-configure-maven-connection-from-kie-server-to-drools-workbench-using-dock

Answer (score 0):

I ended up needing this set of kie-server environment variables:

```
      KIE_WB_PORT: tcp://kie_wb:8001
      KIE_WB_PORT_8001_TCP: tcp://kie_wb:8001
      KIE_WB_PORT_8001_TCP_ADDR: kie_wb
      KIE_WB_PORT_8080_TCP: tcp://kie_wb:8080
      KIE_WB_PORT_8080_TCP_ADDR: kie_wb
      KIE_WB_ENV_KIE_CONTEXT_PATH: business-central
```