# Could not find artifact com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:jar:2.0EA3 in central

Tags: java, maven

`mvn clean install` failed with above error.  In build log:

```
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/sun/xml/bind/jaxb-impl/2.0EA3/jaxb-impl-2.0EA3.pom
Downloading: http://nexus.opencast.org/nexus/content/groups/public/com/sun/xml/bind/jaxb-impl/2.0EA3/jaxb-impl-2.0EA3.pom
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/sun/xml/bind/jaxb-impl/2.0EA3/jaxb-impl-2.0EA3.jar
Downloading: http://nexus.opencast.org/nexus/content/groups/public/com/sun/xml/bind/jaxb-impl/2.0EA3/jaxb-impl-2.0EA3.jar
[WARNING] The POM for com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:jar:2.0EA3 is missing, no dependency information available
```

Did some digging around to find [this prior resolved issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27110014/could-not-find-artifact-in-maven-central-repo-when-search-returns-a-match).  Ok, now I understand that on the repos, it only exists as a pom file, there is no jar.  But how do I move forward?  This won't build without the dependency being resolved.  Please note I'm not a java developer, just trying to get this built and would appreciate help from someone experienced.

Java 11.0.2, Maven 3.3.9

Comment: If you'd bother looking at the repository, you'd see for yourself which versions are available: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.xml.bind/jaxb-impl. As you can see, current latest version is `2.3.2`, so why are you expecting an Early Access version from `2.0` to be available? You could at the very least use the final [`2.0`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.xml.bind/jaxb-impl/2.0) version, instead of a 13-year old Early Access version.

Comment: *"But how do I move forward?"* Remove `EA3`

Comment: You should use https://search.maven.org/  to search in Central...

Comment: @Andreas, did look at the repo but checked search.maven.org - that repo only had 2.0EA3.  Didn't know about mvnrepository.com - first time having to do this.  Thanks for the reference, saved it.

Comment: @khmarbaise, thanks for the reply, see the comment I just posted above.

Comment: You should simply ask https://search.maven.org correctly like this: `https://search.maven.org/search?q=g:com.sun.xml.bind%20a:jaxb-impl` and that will show you 99 possible available versions...

Answer (score 1):

Swapped 2.0EA3 with 2.3.2 for the dependency in pom.xml and build completed successfully.